# Solar panel battery charger

Tags: batteries, solar-cell, charger, panel

I am looking for a way to power my webcam without having to use a long extension cord outside. I have come up with this circuit. Will it work? Can I improve it? [image]

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Instead of the DC-DC converter, you'll want what's called a Maximum Power Point Tracking regulator.  Solar panels have a voltage/current output curve that needs more a little more finesse than a standard buck-boost can do to get optimal output power.  I believe there are a bunch that have BMS built in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That will work somewhat, but the performance will be poor and the DC DC controller won't be a proper load for the solar panel. A solar panel is a variable source with an IV curve.

What you need is an MPPT controller instead of a buck boost converter. Even better, they sell solar charge controllers that integrate BMS, MPPT in one unit.